# Convert SQL to Peewee to assembly a ranking

Tags: python, peewee

I need convert a SQL query to peewee instructions.

My SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    (IFNULL(SUM(`conquista`.`pontos`), 0) + SUM(`statusfase`.`pontos`)) AS `total_pontos`,
    `jogador`.`id` AS `usuario_id`
FROM
    ((`jogador`
    LEFT JOIN `conquista` ON ((`jogador`.`id` = `conquista`.`usuario_id`)))
    JOIN `statusfase` ON ((`jogador`.`id` = `statusfase`.`usuario_id`)))
GROUP BY `jogador`.`id`
ORDER BY `total_pontos` DESC
```

Any ideias?

tks.

Comment: Can you please show us the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at it:

```
(Jogador
 .select(
   (fn.IFNULL(fn.SUM(Conquista.pontos), 0) +
    fn.SUM(StatusFase.pontos)).alias('total_pontos'),
   Jogador.id.alias('usuario_id'))
 .join(Conquista, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(Jogador.id == Conquista.usuario))
 .switch(Jogador)
 .join(StatusFase, on=(Jogador.id == StatusFase.usuario))
 .group_by(Jogador.id)
 .order_by(SQL('total_pontos').desc()))
```

Comment: tks. Works perfect for me.